# How do I specify multiple generic type constraints on a single method?

Tags: c#, generics

I can restrict generics to a specify type using the "Where" clause such as:

```
public void foo<TTypeA>() where TTypeA : class, A
```

How do I do this if my function has two generic types?

```
public void foo<TTypeA, TTypeB>() where TTypeA : class, A && TTypeB : class, B
```

The above doesn't work.  What's the correct syntax to add the rule "TTypeB : class, B"

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
 public void foo<TTypeA, TTypeB>() where TTypeA : class, A 
                                   where TTypeB : class, B
```

Comment: More information about constraints on generic type parameters is available on MSDN, where they describe some of the other kinds of constraints possible (like naked constraints: `where TTypeB : TTypeA`). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 9):

```
public void foo<TTypeA, TTypeB>() where TTypeA : class, A where TTypeB : class, B
```

dang, 20s late. Vote for James Curran, he was first.

Comment: But you have a one-liner 8-)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
 public void foo<TTypeA, TTypeB>() where TTypeA : class where TTypeB : class
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace `&&` with another `where`

Comment: Not correct, only one constraint can be placed without additional Types