# Multiple constraints on generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I have the following four overloads of method Add:

```
    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<TrackInfo> tracks)
    {
        return tracks.Select(t => Add(dataContext, t));
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        return files.Select(f => Add(dataContext, f));
    }

    public TrackInfo Add(DataContext dataContext, TrackInfo track)
    {
        dataContext.TrackInfos.InsertOnSubmit(track);
        Add(track);
        return track;
    }

    public TrackInfo Add(DataContext dataContext, string path)
    {
        return Add(dataContext, new TrackInfo(path));
    }
```

Is there any way to make first and second overload into generic function? Some other abstraction mechanism would also be helpful.

To clarify what I mean (this wont compile!):

```
public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add<T>(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<T> items) where T : TrackInfo, string
{
    return items.Select(i => Add(dataContext, i));
}
```

Firstly, I can't use string as constraint because it's sealed. Secondly I don't think I can specify multiple constraints this way. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I "think" this is what you want

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197849/how-do-i-specify-multiple-generic-type-constraints-on-a-single-method

Comment: So the first and the second overload call the third overload. The fourth overload calls the third and the third calls some unknown fifth overload?

Comment: Add(TrackInfo) is Collection<TrackInfo> member.

Comment: @DerekStrickland unlikely. I think OP wants to magically call one of the non-generic overrides `Add(...TrackInfo track)` and `Add(...string path)` based on generic type, but it can't be done without some runtime resolution - using cleverly placed `dynamic` is common solution to that...

Comment: Just as I thought. Solution to the "problem" would reduce readability too much. I'll just stick with multiple overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best answer but I think this could be what you want:

```
public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add<T>(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<T> tracks) where T : class
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string)) 
    {
        return tracks.Select(t => Add(dataContext, new TrackInfo(t)));
    }
    else if(typeof(T) == typeof(TrackInfo)) 
    {
        return tracks.Select(t => Add(dataContext, t as TrackInfo));
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be string or TrackInfo");
    }
}

public TrackInfo Add(DataContext dataContext, TrackInfo track)
{
    dataContext.TrackInfos.InsertOnSubmit(track);
    Add(track);
    return track;
}

// you may not need this
public TrackInfo Add(DataContext dataContext, string path)
{
    return Add(dataContext, new TrackInfo(path));
}
```

Comment: Works for now, but what happens when TrackInfo is derived to create MP3TrackInfo and CDTrackInfo? Consider using `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` to ensure that children of TrackInfo are correctly handled by your second condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid constant construction by adding an implicit cast to your track info class.

public static implicit operator TrackInfo(string s)
    {
        return new TrackInfo(s);
    }

Going from IEnumerable< string > to IEnumerable< TrackInfo > will require an explicit extension method for conversion. I would leave it as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple generic type constraints; however, when you do so, the types used to close the generic must meet all constraints. This won't be possible to do with a TrackInfo and a string, as they're both "concrete" types (classes) with no inheritance hierarchy possible between them (the System.String class is sealed) and so no type could inherit from both classes.

This code as written looks fine to me. You might shorten the call stack a touch by calling the "primary overload" (the one that takes a single `TrackInfo`) from the `IEnumerable<string>` overload by simply constructing a TrackInfo from the string in the method call (or with a second Select to construct the TrackInfo from each string).

One smell; lambdas used in Select, as a rule, typically should not produce side effects; it's fairly obvious that the Add() method used in the delegate does something other than return a "projection" of the input elements, but for style I'd still prefer code that segregates the projection and addition of the elements even if it ends up more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do total generic because of this part `new TrackInfo(path)`. It's possible to remove the last method with rewriting the second one:

```
public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<TrackInfo> tracks)
{
    return tracks.Select(t => Add(dataContext, t));
}

public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    return Add(dataContext, files.Select(f => new TrackInfo(f));
}

public TrackInfo Add(DataContext dataContext, TrackInfo track)
{
    dataContext.TrackInfos.InsertOnSubmit(track);
    Add(track);
    return track;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got inspired by Wery Nguyen and did full-on generic refactoring in my class. Snippet I posted initially was not the whole problem, but i thought it would explain what I meant. I should just posted the whole thing.

I came up with this:

```
    #region Private methods

    static IEnumerable<TrackInfo> ProcessItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<DataContext, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<TrackInfo>> func)
    {
        using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
        {
            foreach (var item in func(dataContext, items))
            {
                yield return item;
            }

            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<TrackInfo> ProcessItems<T>(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<DataContext, T, TrackInfo> func)
    {
        return items.Select(t => func(dataContext, t));
    }

    TrackInfo ProcessItem<T>(DataContext dataContext, T item, Action<TrackInfo> action)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return ProcessItem(dataContext, this[item as string], action);
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TrackInfo))
        {
            var track = item as TrackInfo;
            action(track);
            return track;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be string or TrackInfo");
    }

    #endregion


    #region Public methods

    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return ProcessItems(items, Add);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Add<T>(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return ProcessItems(dataContext, items, Add);
    }

    public TrackInfo Add<T>(DataContext dataContext, T item)
    {
        return ProcessItem(dataContext, item, 
            i =>
            {
                dataContext.TrackInfos.InsertOnSubmit(i);
                Add(i);
            });
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Delete<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return ProcessItems(items, Delete);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackInfo> Delete<T>(DataContext dataContext, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return ProcessItems(dataContext, items, Delete);
    }

    public TrackInfo Delete<T>(DataContext dataContext, T item)
    {
        return ProcessItem(dataContext, item,
            i =>
            {
                dataContext.TrackInfos.Attach(i);
                dataContext.TrackInfos.DeleteOnSubmit(i);
                Remove(i);
            });
    }
```

There is no redundancy in the code but I'm not sure that readability is all that great. It was fun learning experience nonetheless.

Just to explain. There are two generic ProcessItems and one ProcessItem. Each one is the base method for consecutive overloads of Add and Delete. Those are:

- adding/removing single item,
- adding/removing multiple items,
- adding/removing multiple items with creation of DataContext.

Each singular operation is defined by Action which is propagated trough the chain of calls.
For removing:

```
dataContext.TrackInfos.Attach(i);
dataContext.TrackInfos.DeleteOnSubmit(i);
Remove(i);
```

For adding:

```
dataContext.TrackInfos.InsertOnSubmit(i);
Add(i);
```