# C++ Templates with multiple constraints

Tags: c++, templates, generics, constraints

In C# I am used to specify multiple constraints in a generic method or type as shown right here:
[How do I specify multiple generic type constraints on a single method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197849/how-do-i-specify-multiple-generic-type-constraints-on-a-single-method)

Today I started with C++ for the first time and I am unable to find anything useful when googling for *template multiple constraints*. 
It almost looks like this is not possible and everyone knows it, and thus no questions asked.

I know that in C# generics are much stronger validated by the compiler than in C++, and that is why it feels wrong to me not to be able to constrain my types to multiples super-types.

Comment: google `static_assert`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you usually make constraints on C++ template with `std::enable_if`

here is the trick - if your template looks like this:

```
template <class T>
<return type> <function name> (args...)
```

you take the return type and corporate it with `enable_if` like this :

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<XXX,<return type>>::type
 <function name> (args...)
```

here, `XXX` represents your compile-time condition.

for example: let `add(T1 t1 , T2 t2)` be compiled for only objects that inherit from `Addable`  :

```
template <class T1, class T2>
 typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_base_of<Addable,T1>::value && std::is_base_of<Addable,T2>::value
 decltype(T1()+T2())>::type
 add (T1 t1, T2 t2){
    return t1+t2;
 }
```

Comment: Yea, that is the down-side of using a lower language, grr. It worked, thanks :)

Comment: C++ it's like a drug. we all know C#  is easier and faster to develop, we just too addicted to quite C++ :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is possible in C++ today, but with quite complex syntax. In the next major C++ release we will most likely get a version of [*concepts*](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s), which make this much easier.

In C++14, the C# example you posted might look like this:

```
template <class TResponse, class TRequest,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<MyClass, TRequest>::value &&
                           std::is_base_of<MyOtherClass, TResponse>::value>* = nullptr>
TResponse Call(TRequest request);
```

Comment: The link is certainly a +1. However, this will take quite some time to read.

Comment: It would be available in C++11 if we use `std::enable_if` instead of `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: @ikh what is the difference between the two? They look the same to me in these examples

Comment: @NoelWidmer no difference; It's just helper. `std::enable_if_t<XXXX> * = nullptr` is a bit shorter than `typename std::enable_if<XXXX>::type * = nullptr>`. seealso: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if